# not equal condition in sql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table called `students`.

columns are :

```
student_id
first_name
last_name
address
```

In the output, I want to exclude students having address of "address" or "address, here".

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE address <> 'address' OR address <> 'address, here';
```

it does not work.

it only works with

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE address <> 'address';
```

how to do this?

Comment: You need an `AND` in your condition, not an `OR`

Comment: You can use IS NOT LIKE operator also in mysql. Also you can write AND operator instead of OR operator between two conditions.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
WHERE address NOT IN ('address','address, here')
```

Comment: I very much like the pythonicness of this query! :D

Answer (score 1):

Use AND instead of OR

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE address <> 'address' AND address <> 'address, here';
```

`address <> 'address' OR address <> 'address, here'` will always be true because one address can't be `'address'` and `'address, here'` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
WHERE 
    address <> 'address' 
    AND 
    address <> 'address, here'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE (address <> 'address' AND address <> 'address, here');
```